# How to solve VOLVO VIDA DICE 2014D Error “Can’t Log in”

Tags: volvo

When using VOLVO VIDA DICE 2014D, LOGIN IN the interface can’t enter, adjust the computer time also can’t LOGIN IN.

Thank you very much. Who can solve this problem

Comment: Why do you need to adjust the computer time? Or is this an old install that you have to get around an “out of date” issue?

Comment: Same issue cannot login. I think too it's related to 2018 year, time ajustment isn't allowed...

Answer (score 2):

Then new patch is there

https://www.matthewsvolvosite.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=40&t=83834

EDIT: (Adding the following from the above link - Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2)

From Matthews Volvo Site Forum:

> Solution is easy.
> Patch is self extracting archive. So
>
> Unpack patch used in previous install and find 3 files.
>
> - **filldb.cmd**
> - **filldb.sql**
> - **license**
>
> Edit "license" file. It is XML and can be edited with any text editor. There is string:
>
> **subscriptionExpireDate="2017-12-31 23:59:59"**
>
> Set to whatever date you want and run filldb.cmd

Comment: Thank you very much.I have found a solution to this problem and solved it from http://blog.buyobdii.com/how-to-solve-volvo-vida-dice-2014d-error-cant-log-in/

Comment: Thanks very much. I had the exact same problem. Easy, when you know which buttons to press.